# C++ Template arguments in rust

Tags: generics, rust, macros

Suppose following function in C++

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
T* createFromAllocated(Args&&... args)
{
    // DO STUFF, GET 'address'
    T* ret = new (address) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    return ret;
}
```

The idea of this function is to create T at an already allocated memory location.

My question is especially the part with the arguments that I want to provide to create T. Could there be a nice way in Rust, either with generics or with macros, to do this kind of functionality.

You could do following

```
// Getting the reference from some allocator struct
fn create_from_allocated<T: Default>(&self) -> &mut T {
    // Do stuff
    (*self.location) = T::default();
    self.location
}
```

The problem here is that I'd have to assign the values for T again if I don't want the default values, which feels kind of annoying.

I could imagine to have maybe a custom trait plus some sort of struct to assign them, whose also has a trait, and... it gets too complicated. Maybe some sort of macro could do? If yes, how could I manipulate it to write code at 2 different locations (where I call create_from_allocated and in create_from_allocated (Which I'm pretty sure it's impossible, why would it be?)).

Comment: `create_from_allocated` could take a `t: Option<T>` as an argument. Then you could write `*self.location = t.unwrap_or_default()` to initialize it.

Comment: Given that the main advantage of placement new in C++ is that you're guaranteed the object will constructed in place and not created then moved, and that this guarantee doesn't exist in Rust even if you create the value inside the function, I'd say to take an argument of type `T` and assign it to the place.

Comment: Yeah, seems logical. The value will be moved, no matter what. Maybe the compiler will do some crazy things to avoid moving... I'll have to consult the assembly I guess.